# GCP PHP Flex environment, copy function fails due to lack of permissions

Tags: php, google-app-engine, permissions, copy

Here is my code, it runs locally just fine but when I deploy it, I get a weird error.

```
$url_doc = $url;
    $temp_doc = __DIR__. '/../temp.doc';
    if (!copy($url_doc, $temp_doc)) {
      $content = "Couldn't copy the file....";
    }
```

Here is the error.

```
2017-06-23 21:21:36 default[20170623t151218]  [23-Jun-2017 21:21:36] WARNING: [pool app] child 36 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  copy(/app/app/../temp.doc):
```

How would I correct this?  I am running PHP flex environment on Google app engine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use Cloud Storage for this, all the instances will be able to write and read from it, thus your files would be accessible from all your instances.

Writing to and reading from Cloud Storage is easy,

Write to Cloud Storage

```
$file = 'gs://<your-bucket>/hello.txt';
file_put_contents($file, 'hello world');
```

Read from Cloud Storage

```
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
var_dump($contents);
```

As I know, you can't write to file on Google App Engine. ( The reason I guess is that when the traffic is less, your instance goes down, and the files you have on the instances which get shutdown would be lost.  )

Answer (score 0):

On App Engine Flexible Environment, you can write to file system, but some directories are protected.

For temp files, use `/tmp` dir, or `sys_get_temp_dir` as follows:

```
$temp_doc = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'Doc');
if (!copy($url_doc, $temp_doc)) {
  $content = "Couldn't copy the file....";
}
```